# Apache Server 2.4 permission Error

Tags: html, apache, python-2.7, cgi

The error I am getting goes as following.When I tried to edit the preconfigured html file that apache server comes with, the one that says it works, I get the error access denied.Also I have a second question, I want to use python cgi with html and use that file instead of the preconfig html one, can I simply change the html file for the python one?.There is a snap of the error attached.[Snapshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP4IA.png).

also sorry for the things in spanish it is my main language

Answer (score 0):

> I get the error access denied

Run NotePad as Administrator.

Righclick on notepad icon and click "Run As Administrator".